# RegEx wrap ***** (stars) in tags within string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string `foo ***`; I would like that to be `foo <span>***</span>`

However, the number of `*` could be any amount, so I think I need a JS `replace`???

Comment: Sorry, tried `/(\*+)/, <span>$1</span>` - returned null.

Comment: Put what you've tried in your question.  [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11943774/edit) with the link under it.

Comment: Bugger, was missing the square brackets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
"foo ***".replace(/([\*]+)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```

or, more generally,

```
str.replace(/([\*]+)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vZRa2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var str = 'foo ***';
str = str.replace(/(\*+)/g,function(arg){
    return '<span>' + arg + '</span>';
});
```

Or also:

```
var str = 'foo ***';
str = str.replace(/\*+/g,'<span>$1</span>');
```